# Not centering in CSS

Tags: css

I was wondering if you could possibly tell me why I'm getting some people who say this page isn't centering properly. It seems it shows a scroll bar at the top and bottom of the page. If anyone has any ideas, I'd really appreciate it.

```
<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


<style type="text/css">  


<link href="//cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/classic-081711.css" 
 rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">
#mc_embed_signup{background:#fff; clear:left; font:24px Helvetica,Arial,sans-
serif; }
/* Add your own MailChimp form style overrides in your site stylesheet or in 
this style block.
   We recommend moving this block and the preceding CSS link to the HEAD of 
your HTML file. */



h1, h2, h3, body, html,.ow_page_container {
 color: #000000; 
}
body, html{
   line-height: 1.2;
}

body, body.ow {
 background-image: url('images/'); 
background-repeat: ; 
background-color: #fff; 
}
.maintenance_cont {
 width: 100%; 
margin: 0 auto; 
 padding-top: 0px; 
}


html, body{
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    }
h1, h2, h3, body{
    font-family: "Arial", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.topp{

    background-image: url('http://gamermeld.com/ow_userfiles/themes
/theme_image_76.jpg');
    background-color: #F8F8F8 ;
    width: 100%;
    height: 430px;
    }

.second{
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 430px;
}
    .secondword{
         position:absolute;
         top: 30px;
         left: 420px;
        font-size: 50px;
    }
    .secondp{
        position:absolute;
        top: 80px;
        left: 1020px;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 40px;
    }
    .secondimage{
        position: absolute;
        top: 190px;
        left: 1250px;
    }
    .secondwordtwo{
        position:absolute;
        top: 300px;
        left: 1200px;
        font-size: 30px;
        font-style: italic;
    }
    .arrow{
        position: absolute;
        top: 370px;
        left: 1250px;
    }
.third{
    position: relative;
    background-color: #D8D8D8;
    width: 100%;
    height: 430px;
}
    .thirdword{
        position:absolute;
        top: 50px;
        left: 350px;
        font-size: 38px;
    }
    .thirdp{
        position:absolute;
        top:120px;
        left:350px;
        font-size: 26px;
        width: 670px;
    }
    .thirdpic{
        position:absolute;
        top: 25px;
        left:1150px;
    }
    .arrowthird{
        position: absolute;
        top: 370px;
        left: 650px;
    }
.fourth{
    position: relative;
    height: 430px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
}
    .fourthpic{
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        left: 410px;

    }
    .fourthword{
        position: absolute;
        top: 100px;
        left: 950px;
        font-size: 38px;
        width: 500px;
    }
    .fourthp{
        position: absolute;
        top: 170px;
        left: 950px;
        font-size: 26px;
        width: 650px;
    }
    .arrowfourth{
        position: absolute;
        top: 370px;
        left: 1250px;
    }
.fifth{
    position: relative;
    height: 430px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #D8D8D8;
}
    .fifthword{
        position: absolute;
        top: 130px;
        left: 350px;
        font-size: 38px;
    }
    .fifthp{
        position: absolute;
        top:200px;
        left:350px;
        font-size: 26px;
        width: 670px;
    }
    .fifthpic{
        position: absolute;
        top: 30px;
        left: 1100px;
        font-size: 26px;
        width: 650px;
    }
    .arrowfifth{
        position: absolute;
        top: 370px;
        left: 650px;
    }
.sixth{
    position: relative;
    height: 430px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
}
    .sixthpic{
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        left: 410px;
    }
    .sixthword{
        position: absolute;
        top: 150px;
        left: 950px;
        font-size: 38px;
        width: 500px;
    }
    .sixthp{
        position: absolute;
        top: 210px;
        left: 950px;
        font-size: 26px;
        width: 650px;
    }
    .arrowsixth{
        position: absolute;
        top: 370px;
        left: 1250px;
    }
.seventh{
    position: relative;
    height: 430px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #D8D8D8;
}
    .seventhword{
        position: absolute;
        top: 130px;
        left: 350px;
        font-size: 38px;
    }
    .seventhp{
        position: absolute;
        top:200px;
        left:350px;
        font-size: 26px;
        width: 670px;
    }
     .seventhpic{
        position: absolute;
        top: 30px;
        left: 1100px;
        font-size: 26px;
        width: 650px;
    }


    .facebook{
    position:relative;
    top: 100px;
    left: 900px;
            width: 200px;
}
.faceword{
    position:relative;
    top: -50px;
    left:750px;
    font-size: 30px;
            width: 600px;
}
 .form{
  position: absolute;
 top: 100px;
 left: 400px;
width: 500px;
height: 400px;
 }

.wrap{
width: 1898px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
</style>
</head>




<body>
<div class="wrap">

<div class="topp"></div>

<div class="second">

<div class="form">
```

Comment: Post a screenshot of the problem since we can't replicate it with the code you provided.

Comment: Your code means nothing.

Comment: at the first look, you have an extra <style type="text/css">   at the top of the page. please remove it.  And also, is it for EDM or just a webpage? if it is for an EDM, you shouldn't use external css file for that.

Comment: what Ryan said .. your  <link href="//cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/classic-081711.css" 
 rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> should not be in the style block, so remove the <style type="text/css"> tag above it and see where you stand.  If problem persists try posting a fiddle

Comment: It still doesn't seem to work. Basically, I want to make it center no matter how much zoomed in it is.

Answer (score 0):

Your `.wrap` class is set to 1898px i assume you want that at 100%: your missing closing tags for your `<div>'s`, Your second  had a background color of white, i assume you wanted to show the image, removed the color. also made form at 33.3% width and form left is at 33.3% to center the form from 100%.

```css
#mc_embed_signup {
    background:#fff;
    clear:left;
    font:24px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
/* Add your own MailChimp form style overrides in your site stylesheet or in 
this style block.
   We recommend moving this block and the preceding CSS link to the HEAD of 
your HTML file. */
 h1, h2, h3, body, html, .ow_page_container {
    color: #000000;
}
body, html {
    line-height: 1.2;
}
body, body.ow {
    background-image: url('images/');
    background-repeat:;
    background-color: #fff;
}
.maintenance_cont {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 0px;
}
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
h1, h2, h3, body {
    font-family:"Arial", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.topp {
    background: #F8F8F8 url('http://gamermeld.com/ow_userfiles/themes/theme_image_76.jpg');
 background-size: 100%;
}
.second {
    
    
    width: 100%;
    height: 430px;
}
.form{
 position: absolute;
 top: 99px;
 left: 33.3%;
 width: 33.3%;
 height: 400px;
 z-index: 1000;
 text-align: center;
 }

.wrap {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/classic-081711.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="wrap">
    <div class="topp">
        <div class="second">
            <div class="form">this is the form...</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```